# XML ingest into Hive Table with Serde hows class not found issue

Tags: hive, xml-parsing, hive-serde

I am trying to ingest a simple xml to hive table. Table is  created fine but when executing select query or any other query on that table getting below error:

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: RuntimeException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat

I followed [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/content/kbentry/972/hive-and-xml-pasring.html) article.

What is the problem here?

I can see that jar file is added.

```
list jars; 
/tmp/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar
```

And that the jar file has class for which I am getting error.

```
[root@sandbox-hdp tmp]# jar -tf hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar | grep -icom.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat
com/ibm/spss/hive/serde2/xml/XmlInputFormat$XmlRecordReader.class
com/ibm/spss/hive/serde2/xml/XmlInputFormat.class
```

Comment: can you run following command from your box and pate the output. this one from hive `list jars;` and this one from your terminal,  `jar -tf <jar you downloaded> | grep -i com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat`

Comment: yes, i did. Got the below output:hive> list jars;
/tmp/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar ,,, other one gave me: [root@sandbox-hdp tmp]# jar -tf hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar | grep -i com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat
com/ibm/spss/hive/serde2/xml/XmlInputFormat$XmlRecordReader.class
com/ibm/spss/hive/serde2/xml/XmlInputFormat.class

Answer (score 0):

Ther are couple of things to be careful at:
1. Check the xml file, specially the quotation character(").i was having issue with  ” instead of ".
2. Hive user has permission to read the jar? Try to chmod 777 to the jar.
3. Add jar file if this is a fresh start of hive.
4.If through ambari you want to execute query : every time have the statement of "add jar.."
5. To get rid of add jar every time you need to add the jar to amabri user with hdfs:
add jar hdfs:///tmp/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;
or anothe option you can follow [Here.](https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/48734/how-to-permanently-add-custom-jar-files-to-hive-in.html)